# ¿Como puedo obtener el rango de las fechas? (SQL)

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, pgadmin

Tengo siguiente tabla:

precio <pid PK FK, comercio: PK FK, fecha_registro: PK, precio>

Como puedo obtener el precio de un producto desde la fecha más antigua hasta la más reciente?

Answer (score 0):

puedes obtener los precios de los productos ordenados desde la fecha mas Antigua hasta la fecha Reciente Utilizando la siguiente linea de codigo.

```
SELECT precio.fecha_registro, precio.pid, 
precio.precio FROM precio 
WHERE precio.pid LIKE 'XXXXXX'
ORDER BY precio.fecha_registro ASC
```

NOTA: Yo supuse que tu tabla se llama **precio**

- si quieres que te muestre un producto especifico?
  debes colocar en vez de las XXXXXX,  el pid del producto que deseas buscar (NOTA: sin quitar las comillas)
- si quieres que te muestre todos los productos que tengas en tu tabla?
  debes colocar en vez de las XXXXXX, el simbolo %  (NOTA: sin quitar las comillas)

esta Instrucción de SQL te mostrara la Lista de tus productos Ordenados por fecha desde la fecha mas antigua a la mas actual.